# How does room Size affect the dB level in the room?

Tags: sound-design, sound, noise, noise-reduction

So basically I had an early question and found out that if I have 15 machines running at 80 dB in a room it should end up being around 10*Log(15(10^7.5)) dB approx. 91.76 dB.

But how would the room size and the dispersion of the machines affect this number? As well as distance from the machines.

Edit: You can assume the machines run at a constant 75 dB and have the sound/pitch of a computer fan. For the sake of trying to find a general formula you can assume any other variables in your answer as long as you explain them.

Edit: I understand that there may be many more variables that come into play when determining the sound intensity in a room. But I am trying to find a rough estimate.

Comment: This feels like it could turn into the audio version of the Coastline Paradox (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox). - Could you tell us what problem you're trying to solve here? The solution might be less complex than you think.

Comment: Yes, so basically I have x machines running in a room, and they are running at 75 decibels. I do not have specific dimensions, but I plan to insert some assumptions that include 1000-2000 square-foot rooms. Let me know if this helps and if certain parts should be added to the question itself.

Comment: I got that. But what problem are you trying to solve by answering this question? Why do you need to know how loud this room will be?

Comment: This is another of those "how long is a piece of string?" questions. Put them in Wembley Arena & go stand over the far side, you'll never hear them at all. Put them evenly-spaced in a concrete 1000sq ft room & stand in the middle, they'll be loud. Standing waves/resonances compared to the actual pitches & periods these as-yet-to-be-described machines output make this unanswerable. Are we talking 90dB of squealing grinders, or thrumming pumps, or metal punches peaking in volume only every 10 seconds?

Comment: @Tetsujin Well I just wanted to know how size of room and distance from the machines affects any of this mathematically. I understand there are other factors at play, but I am also working off of assumptions so it is hard to add more detail when I have to add some assumptions as well.

Comment: Not that I know how to do math so complex for anything like this - but there is not even enough information here for so much as a rough guess.

Comment: Well in any estimate or guess one should be able to tell me how the size of a room and closeness of the machines affects dB. This is just the fact of any formula everything changes the answers by some proportion. I just want to know how these two "variables" in an equation that may include other unknowns affect another. Ex. volume = b*w*h width is directly proportional to the rest of the variables if it is 10 times larger than before the volume is 10 times larger.

Comment: You seem to be studiously avoiding adding any detail requested. As it stands this is completely unanswerable.

Comment: Its alright figured out how distance affects the sound intensity elsewhere since it was a struggle for you. If you are experiencing 100 dB at 1 meter and then move back to 100 meters. You convert 100 dB to W/m^2 and then multiply it by 1/100^2 and convert it back to dB. Now you know!

Comment: But that only works in open space. It doesn't take into account the reflections from walls multiplying or nullifying amplitude at different frequencies and different wall distances. Then there's absorption and diffusion... Please just tell us why you want to make these calculations - what problem will they solve for you? Then we might be able to give you a sensible answer.

Comment: Yes I understand this, I am righting up sound estimates for a server type building. I wasn't given dimensions of the building, what it will be made of or much at all. Hence I am looking for some rough estimates that given such little information will most likely be over estimates. Apologies for getting a little passive aggressive but I was having a hard time as is trying to learn as much about this stuff as I could.

Comment: In that case, you might be better off in an IT/Computing forum where you can ask someone with experience how to write those estimates - You're unlikely to be the first to do so and you'd probably get a much better answer than you will here